# How to limit number of lines per file written using FileIO

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a possible way to limit number of lines in each written shard using TextIO or may be FileIO?

Example:

1. Read rows from Big Query - Batch Job (Result is 19500 rows for example).
2. Make some transformations.
3. Write files to Google Cloud storage (19 files, each file is limited to 1000 records, one file has 500 records).
4. Cloud Function is triggered to make a POST request to an external API for each file in GCS.

Here is what I'm trying to do so far but doesn't work (Trying to limit 1000 rows per file):

```
BQ_DATA = p | 'read_bq_view' >> beam.io.Read(
        beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query,
                               use_standard_sql=True)) | beam.Map(json.dumps)

BQ_DATA | beam.WindowInto(GlobalWindows(), Repeatedly(trigger=AfterCount(1000)),
                              accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
        | WriteToFiles(path='fileio', destination="csv")
```

Am I conceptually wrong or is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Do you want to arbitrarily assign number of rows in a file or is it based on some logic ? Also, can you elaborate on the usecase?

Comment: @JayadeepJayaraman Yes I want to arbitrarily assign number of rows in a file where each file is limited to 1000 number of rows. I have edited my question adding more details about the actual use case.

Comment: Is this a batch job? Triggers are ignored in batch jobs.

Comment: Yes it's batch. Thank Peter for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the write to GCS step inside ParDo and limit the number of elements to include in a "batch" like this:

```
from apache_beam.io import filesystems

class WriteToGcsWithRowLimit(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, row_size=1000):
    self.row_size = row_size
    self.rows = []

  def finish_bundle(self):
     if len(self.rows) > 0:
        self._write_file()

  def process(self, element):
    self.rows.append(element)
    if len(self.rows) >= self.row_size:
        self._write_file()

  def _write_file(self):
    from time import time
    new_file = 'gs://bucket/file-{}.csv'.format(time())
    writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create(path=new_file)
    writer.write(self.rows) # may need to format
    self.rows = []
    writer.close()
```

```
BQ_DATA  | beam.ParDo(WriteToGcsWithRowLimit())
```

Note that this will not create any files with less than 1000 rows, but you can change the logic in `process` to do that.

(Edit 1 to handle the remainders)

(Edit 2 to stop using counters, as files will be overridden)

Comment: That worked, thanks Peter. I just formatted the `writer.write` format to be 
```for row in self.rows:
writer.write((str(row) + "\n").encode(encoding='UTF-8'))```

Comment: @HazemSayed Awesome :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution works for only total of 1000 elements. Which means if my Pcollection has 1001, it will process only 1000. One element is discarded. Any tips here @peter-kim

Comment: Thank you Peter, you are awesome! I already handled the reminders in my code but overriding `finish_bundle` is of course better. However the problem with this approach that it only processes/writes a PCollection that has maximum of 1000 elements. For example, BQ DATA is 2000 elements, `row_size=100` the result is 10 files where it should be 20 files with 100 records in each.

Comment: @HazemSayed I just realized that using a counter isn't an ideal solution, as it'll overwrite files.

Comment: You could use BatchElements https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.transforms.util.html#apache_beam.transforms.util.BatchElements followed by a DoFn that writes the whole batch. Care needs to be taken to abandon files from discarded bundles as well (see Beam's implementation https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py).